# How do I get a value from a textbox from a WinForm and then put it in a textbox in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

Say I have a textBox named "inputTextBox" in WPF

```
<TextBox x:Name="inputTextBox" />
```

And the I have a textBox in Windows Forms named "funcTextBox" 
What I want to happen is like this:

```
<TextBox x:Name="inputTextBox" Text=<funcTextBox.Text> />
```

Is there a way to that ? 
Note: I have successfully hosted the WPF usercontrol in my Windows Form already. My concern is on how to access that "funcTextBox" from WinForms and then transfer the value to "inputTextBox" in WPF control

Comment: do it in code behind => xaml.cs

Comment: Yes I know that the code should be in xaml.cs. I just don't have any idea on that. Do you have a sample code to do that ?

Comment: Luca C,. provided needed code. One thing you have to keep in mind is that the forms textbox must be accessible on the corresponding  xaml window

Comment: This is a pretty basic question, and can be found everywhere on Google.

Comment: Access the WPF TextBox through the ElementHost. Please show your code if you want any further help.

Answer (score 0):

The code you wrote is XAML. For do that I should use code behind.

```
funcTextBox.Text = inputTextBox.Text;
```